# How do you allow the .shtml extension with webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, shtml

My company has shared resources and uses *.shtml to keep the same look and feel across the intranet.  When developing on my local machine, how can I tell webpack-dev-server to use it?  It downloads the file instead.